# how can I modify my jQuery function to update the number counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing number counter in one of my section. When I add new betslips to the container the numbers are displaying correctly. However, when I delete any of the row the counter is not getting updated. For example if there are 3 rows numbered 1, 2 and 3 and if I delete row number 2 the updated values are 1 and 3. Infact the counter should reset to 1 and 2.

Here is my JS code

Adding the betslip rows

```
function createSingleBetDiv(betInfo) {
    var id = betInfo['betType'] + '_' + betInfo['productId'] + '_' + betInfo['mpid'],
        div = createDiv(id + '_div', 'singleBet', 'bet gray2'),
        a =  createA(null, null, null, null, 'right orange'),
        leftDiv = createDiv(null, null, 'left'),
        closeDiv = createDiv(null, null, 'icon_shut_bet'),
        singleBetNumber = ++document.getElementsByName('singleBet').length;

    // Info abt the bet
    $(leftDiv).append('<p class="title"><b>' + singleBetNumber + '.&nbsp;' + betInfo['horseName'] + '</b></p>');
    var raceInfo = "";
    $("#raceInfo").contents().filter(function () {
        if (this.nodeType === 3) raceInfo = $(this).text() + ',&nbsp;' + betInfo['betTypeName'] + ' (' + betInfo['value'] + ')';
    });
    $(leftDiv).append('<p class="title">' + raceInfo + '</p>');

    // Closing btn
    (function(id) {
        a.onclick=function() {
            removeSingleBet(id + '_div');
        };
    })(id);
    $(a).append(closeDiv);

    // Creating input field
    $(leftDiv).append('<p class="supermid"><input id="' + id + '_input\" type="text"></p>');

    // Creating WIN / PLACE checkbox selection
    $(leftDiv).append('<p><input id="' + id + '_checkbox\" type="checkbox"><b>' + winPlace + '</b></p>');

    // Append left part
    $(div).append(leftDiv);
    // Append right part
    $(div).append(a);
    // Appending div with data
    $.data(div, 'mapForBet', betInfo);

    return div;
}
```

Function to remove betslip

```
function removeSingleBet(id) {

    // Remove the div
    removeElement(id);

    // Decrease the betslip counter
    decreaseBetSlipCount();

    // Decrease bet singles counter
    updateBetSinglesCounter();
}

function decreaseBetSlipCount() {
    var length = $("#racingBetSlipCount").text().length,
        count = $("#racingBetSlipCount").text().substring(1, length-1),
        text;
    count = parseInt(count);

    if (!isNaN(count)) count--;
    if (count == 0) text = noSelections;
    else text = count;
    $("#racingBetSlipCount").text('(' + text + ')');
}
```

Comment: show your betslip html structure.

Comment: I am populating all the inner content using JS. However here is the HTML structure of betslip <div id="bets"></div>

Comment: @Subash Selvaraj I have also added the link to my dev site in my question.

Comment: you mean `<div id="bets"><div id="bet"></div><div id="bet"></div></div>` like this?

Comment: no just <div id="bets"></div>. All other inner content are generated through JS

Comment: I would recommend using a binding framework that update that automatically like knockout.js. It's more simple than doing it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage to do that with following steps;

Enclose bet no with `span`,

```
$(leftDiv).append('<p class="title"><b><span class="bet_no">' + singleBetNumber + '<span>.&nbsp;' + betInfo['horseName'] + '</b></p>');
```

and I assume you have aouter div called "your_div"

Call below function after every increase and decrease event

```
function updateBetNo() {
    var counter = 1;
    $("#your_div .bet_no").each(function(i, val) {
        $(this).text(counter);
        counter++;
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about val()? From the docs: `The .val() method is primarily used to get the values of form elements`.

Answer (score 4):

This could be done using only CSS, e.g:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KcWMv/)

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="bets">
        <div class="bet">  some content</div>
        <div class="bet">  some content</div>
        <div class="bet">  some content</div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#bets {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

#bets .bet {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

#bets .bet::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

All row number will be updated automatically when adding/removing any row.

Comment: Wow, that's really impressive.

Comment: It works. I will vote up for your answer. But I will accept another answer since I am going to use that one.

Answer (score 0):

Make the betNumber findable:

```
$(leftDiv).append('<p class="title"><b><span class="singleBetNumber">' + singleBetNumber + '</span>.&nbsp;' + betInfo['horseName'] + '</b></p>');
```

After an insert or delete renumber:

```
$('.singleBedNumber').each(function(idx, el) {
    $(el).html('' + (idx + 1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is that $("#racingBetSlipCount") is likely not selecting what you think it is. Since #racingBetSlipCount is an id selector it will only select one item.

To me you need to wrap the betnumber in something accessible so you can update it without having to parse through the title.

So first you would update the creation of the betTitle:

```
$(leftDiv).append('<p class="title"><b><span class=\'betNum\'>' + singleBetNumber + '</span>.&nbsp;' + betInfo['horseName'] + '</b></p>');
```

Then you can loop through each and update the number appropriately.

```
var count = 1;
$.each($(".betNum"), function(){
    $(this).html(count++);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only works when I add another bet after I delete any of the bet in my list. It does reset the counter after a new bet is added, but doesn't work if i delete the bet.